# Use same mongodb database over Windows 7 & Ubuntu

Tags: windows, mongodb, ubuntu, windows-7, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to use the same MongoDB database I use on windows 7 as I do on Ubuntu.

On Ubuntu, I went into the file: `/etc/mongodb.conf`

and changed `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` to `dbpath=/media/meaniostack/OS/data/db` which is the database on the windows partition.

When I tried starting up mongod & mongo, I got the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: test
2015-01-30T14:19:11.027-0500 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-01-30T14:19:11.028-0500 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

However, when I go back to `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`, it works like normal. Keep in mind, that I have mounted `media/meaniostack/OS`

How do I make this work, and is it possible? Does mongodb, use a different type of storage compared to the one in Ubuntu?

Comment: The files should be usable from the windows machine without modification (though you might see slow allocation of files since you would then not be using ext4 or XFS).  I suspect a permissions issue os the root cause of the problem, what do the logs say when you attempt to start with dbpath=/media/meaniostack/OS/data/db?

Comment: The error you've provided is from the `mongo` shell which suggests `mongod` didn't start successfully (or isn't listening on that port). More relevant errors on why `mongod` failed to start should be in the log file, which the Ubuntu package defaults to: `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. Also note that you can only have the data files open by one `mongod` instance at a time (i.e. your Ubuntu server can't be using the data directory while your Windows server is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of messing around I found the solution to be:

1. Alter permissions to the folders that the database is in.
2. Change the mongodb.conf path variable
3. Use `mongod --dbpath /media/meaniostack/OS/data/db` instead of: `service mongod start`

Hope this helped anyone with a similar issue.